# Calculate seconds from now to specified time today or tomorrow

Tags: python, time, timedelta

I would have thought this question would already have an answer, but it doesn't seem to. In Python, I want to calculate the number of seconds from "now" to a specified time "today" or "tomorrow," whenever it next occurs (e.g., the next occurrence of 6:30 AM). The plan is to count down seconds and set off a musical alarm at the specified time. I'm pretty new at Python, and the `datetime` documentation hasn't helped me with this so far. Can somebody give me some assistance with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
(timedelta(hours=24) - (now - now.replace(hour=6, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0))).total_seconds() % (24 * 3600)
```

Comment: Please give an explanation for your code

Answer (score 3):

```
In [12]: dt = datetime.datetime.now()
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 23, 4, 8, 36, 742436)

In [14]: six_thirty = datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 23, 06, 30, 0, 0)

In [15]: six_thirty - dt
Out[15]: datetime.timedelta(0, 8483, 257564)
```

## Notes

The datetime object is formatted in year, month, day, hour, min, second, millisecond.

The timedelta object gives the difference in days, seconds, microseconds, so for this example, there are 8483 seconds until 630 am, which translates to roughly 2 hrs and 21 minutes and 23 seconds.

Comment: This works if the current time is before 6:30 AM. If it's after, this gives a negative timedelta, i.e., the time from 6:30 AM today until now, e.g.: `datetime.timedelta(-1, 83679, 286255)`. I also need to be able to calculate the time from now until 6:30 AM tomorrow.

Comment: Oops, hold on: there weren't 83679 seconds from 6:30 today until now, and if I change the future date to tomorrow it gives `datetime.timedelta(0, 83679, 286255)`. So maybe I just need to take the seconds and disregard the `-1` if I get one! If anyone can explain why this works this way, I'd like to see the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty sharp! And now for the whole thing, from the AM/PM time to the seconds remaining (there's probably a way to do this in fewer lines of code, but this works):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> futime = '10:30 AM'
>>> fustrip = futime.rstrip(' AM')
>>> fusplit = fustrip.split(':')
>>> hr = int(fusplit[0])
>>> min = int(fusplit[1])
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> secsleft = int((timedelta(hours=24) - (now - now.replace(hour=hr, minute=min, second=0, microsecond=0))).total_seconds() % (24 * 3600))
>>> secsleft
2063
```

That's where the time (10:30 AM) is today. For 6:30 tomorrow, it works too:

```
>>> hr = 6
>>> secsleft = int((timedelta(hours=24) - (now - now.replace(hour=hr, minute=min, second=0, microsecond=0))).total_seconds() % (24 * 3600))
>>> secsleft
74063
```

Comment: Just noticed: since this code uses 24-hour time, of course you have to add 12 to the hours for PM times!