# How do you make a countdown bot in discord using python

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that if you told it to make a countdown to e.g. *7:00 pm*, it would make a countdown to that time, then send a message e.g. *@everyone countdown finished* and I want it if the user typed cancel, the countdown cancels

**Please note that I want it to be like an alarm clock, not a timer**

I already made everything except the countdown and the message after the countdown

**here is the code for now**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "m!")

@client.command(aliases = ["countdown"])
async def countdown_at(ctx, time):
    await ctx.send(f"OK\countdown made to {time}")
```

Comment: you might want to use asyncio create_task and asyncio sleep

Comment: Damn, this question got 1k views, never expected that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it,
here it is:

```
@bot.command()
async def alarm(ctx, time)
    now = datetime.now()
    mtimeA = time
    mtimeB = mtimeA.split(":")
    hr = int(mtimeB[0])
    min = int(mtimeB[1])
    secsleft = int((timedelta(hours=24) - (now - now.replace(hour=hr, minute=min, second=0, microsecond=0))).total_seconds() % (24 * 3600))
    await ctx.send(f"OK\nAlarm set to {time}")
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.content.lower() == "cancel alarm"
    try:
        await bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=secsleft)
        await ctx.send("Alarm cancelled")
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} alarm finished")
```

All this does is it takes the time, ex. "19:20", and splits it into 2 values "[19, 20]". Then it converts the time given into seconds with timedelta. Lastly, it waits for "cancel alarm", if it didn't get this message and the alarm is done, it sends a message notifying the user that his alarm is done

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timeout` on `wait_for` for your timer, while waiting for the cancellation message:

```
@bot.command()
async def ex(ctx, time: int):
    await ctx.send("Countdown started")
    def check(message):
        return message.channel == ctx.channel and message.author == ctx.author and message.content.lower() == "cancel"
    try:
        m = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=time)
        await ctx.send("Countdown cancelled")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.guild.default_role} countdown finished")
```

Comment: @AbdullahAlawad changing it to `{ctx.guild.default_role}` fixes the `@@`, not sure why.

Comment: still gonna use it as a placeholder for now

Comment: You might be able to combine it with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810003/calculate-seconds-from-now-to-specified-time-today-or-tomorrow

Comment: where should I put it exactly, I never made bots before, so I don't know